# Dropnet getting access token cant peform 3rd step of 0auth

Tags: c#, dropnet

Hi guys im trying to use dropnet as means to be using dropbox as a cloud storage for my application, and following the 3 step process using the normal 0auth

1.Get Request Token[done]

2.Send user for authorization, and get back verifier[done]

3.Get Access token using the original Request Token and the verifier[issue!]

if i understand the api correctly since i want to use a single account for my storage i need api key,api secret,token and secret.the token and secret seems to be accessible from the third steps and its my trouble.

from the second step i get this url

https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxx

before pressing authenticate to allow my app to use dropbox

from the documentation i read that you need to use this method
 UserLogin GetAccessToken(string code, string redirectUri);

i am assuming here xxxxx is the string code
to validate that is the original

so i made code as follows

```
var accessToken = client.GetAccessToken("xxxxxxx","https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxx);
            var ats =accessToken.Secret;
            var att = accessToken.Token;
 Console.Writeline(ats);
Console.Writeline(att):
```

in hopes of getting the console to print my secret and token for my acct but it dosent work ?Giving me the error of

An unhandled exception of type 'DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxRestException' occurred in DropNet.dll

help please !

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself,here is the full code

```
DropNetClient client = new DropNetClient(variable.ApiKey, variable.ApiSecret);



]
           var response =client.GetToken();
            var t = response.Token;
            var s = response.Secret;
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine(t);
            var authorizeUrl = client.BuildAuthorizeUrl(new DropNet.Models.UserLogin
            {
                Secret = s,
                Token = t

            }
                );

            DropNetClient client2= new DropNetClient(variable.ApiKey, variable.ApiSecret,t,s);


            // Prompt for user to auth
            Process.Start(authorizeUrl);
            // PRESS KEY AFTER authorization AFTER
            Console.ReadKey();

          // If the user authed, let's get that token
          try
            {
                var Token = client2.GetAccessToken();
                var userToken = Token.Token;
                var userSecret = Token.Secret;
                Console.WriteLine(userSecret);//ACCESS TOKEN SECRET
                Console.WriteLine(userToken);//ACCESS TOKEN
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception! " + e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
            // save for later
```